# Moving/Resizing another window and re-draw it?

Tags: c#, resize, window, move

I'm trying to resize a window using:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool rePaint);
```

This resizes the window as I want to. Unfortunately, the elements inside of the window are not scaling like they would if I used the mouse. I suppose using the mouse fires off a re-draw event and `MoveWindow()` doesn't.

So is there a way I can resize another window and make it re-draw, or are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function which allows you to specify as flags whether the window should be redrawn or not, also whether it should be resized, etc.

Comment: Can you tell the specefic flag?

Comment: As most of the flags start with `SWP_NO...`, I'd just **not** specify `SWP_NOSIZE` and `SWP_NOREDRAW` and give it a try.